# List entries by category

Tags: entries, categories, category

I have a number of entries that all belong under a Channel that I created. Each entry has a category field where the user can select one or many categories to associate the entry with.

I am displaying these entries on my page, but would like to display each entry under the appropriate category.

For example, my entries are currently displayed like this:

- Entry 1 (Category A)
- Entry 2 (Category C)
- Entry 3 (Category A)
- Entry 4 (Category B)
- Entry 5 (Category A)

I want it to display like this:

- Entry 1 (Category A)
- Entry 3 (Category A)
- Entry 5 (Category A)
- Entry 4 (Category B)
- Entry 2 (Category C)

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This will exclude empty categories, meaning they don't have any entries associated with them.

```
{% set entryIds = craft.entries.section('channelHandle').ids() %}
{% set categories = craft.categories.relatedTo({ sourceElement: entryIds }).group('categoryGroupHandle') %}

{% for category in categories %}
    <h2>{{ category.title }}</h2>
    <ul>
        {% set entries = craft.entries.section('channelHandle').relatedTo(category) %}
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```